# Weird sprintf side effect?

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on PSET 4 in CS50 and seem to have a problem with sprintf changing unrelated variables. I am only giving the code that doesn't reveal my solution...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

int counter = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ifilename = argv[1];

    //open file in read only
    FILE *file = fopen(ifilename, "r");

    BYTE buffer[512];
    int bsize = fread(&buffer, 512, 1, file);

    printf("BSIZE IS %d\n", bsize);
    char ofilename[7];
    printf("BSIZE IS %d\n", bsize);
    sprintf(ofilename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
    printf("BSIZE IS %d\n", bsize);
    FILE *img = fopen(ofilename, "w");
```

...
As you see on these final few lines, I am trying to figure out what is happening to my bsize...
My output when I run the program is as follows:

```
BSIZE IS 1
BSIZE IS 1
BSIZE IS 0
```

What's the cause of the trouble?

Comment: Change `char ofilename[7];` to `char ofilename[270];` or some other sensible large number.  You've got a buffer overflow; since the buffer is on the stack, it could be regarded as a Stack Overflow.

Comment: Keep in mind that **at bare minimum** you need space for the NUL delimiter at the end of any string.

Comment: Any good reason you are not checking the return value from `fopen`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...the OP's clear reasoning is that with a format string of `%03i.jpg`, they need three bytes for the number, plus four bytes for `.jpg`. If you want to argue for a far larger value, it'd be worth trying to explain why their original reading was wrong. (That numbers can be larger than three digits and cause the format string to emit more than three numbers is part of it, so just moving to an 8-byte string isn't adequate).

Answer (score 3):

```
char ofilename[7];
```

Is too short, when you `sprintf(` it messes up neighboring values.

On Linux systems the max possible length is `MAX_PATH` which is potentially quite long (4096 characters).

Comment: Specifically, the `0` that's intended to be the NUL at the end of the string is overwriting the next byte.

Comment: The format string is `"%03i.jpg"` -- that's much shorter than `MAX_PATH`, so I don't know why you bring the latter up.

Comment: @Mikhail, actually [MAX_PATH is a known security concern, since actual pathnames might be longer](https://eklitzke.org/path-max-is-tricky)... longer pathnames should be protected against or dealt with. (edit: also see [file system limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) where some are limitless).

Comment: Thank you very much, all the comments and this answer were helpful!

Comment: In principle, you should use something like `int len = snprintf(ofilename, sizeof(ofilename), "%03i.jpg", counter);` and then check that `len` is both greater than zero and less than `sizeof(ofilename)`, worrying about signed vs unsigned comparisons.